# Fill missing Dates in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, which looks like this.

[image: dataframe]

It has 8 columns and n rows. The first column is a date where are missing days. (Like 1946-01-04 etd...) But Also there are duplicates(like 1946-01-02) I would like a code which perseve this duplicates, but also fill missing dates and add `NaN` to the others cells in row.

I tried this

```py
dfx = pd.DataFrame(None, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start=df.地震の発生日時.min(), end=df.地震の発生日時.max(), freq='D'))
df = df.apply(pd.concat([df, dfx], join='outer', axis=1))
```

but it just added from `.min()` to `.max()` at the end of the file... I would like to apply it inside the data like

```
Date        Time        Places  w     x      y    z
1946-01-02  14:45:00    6.8   36.3  140.1   31  3.2 1
1946-01-02  22:18:00    7.6   40.5  141.4   0   4.6 3
1946-01-02  23:29:00    6.7   36.1  139.4   39  4.3 2
1946-01-03  04:28:00    5.6   34.4  136.5   1   4.2 2
1946-01-03  04:36:00    6.5   35.5  139.5   50  3   1
1946-01-04  00:00:00    NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN NaN NaN
1946-01-06  10:56:00    8.1   41.5  143.4   51  5.2 3
```

Btw. I'm not able to use `inner join`. It throws:
`AttributeError: 'Places' is not a valid function for 'Series' object`

Comment: In Data is only first column `Date` in index, `DatetimeIndex` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution if first column is filled `DatetimeIndex` with no times:

```
print (df)
                Time  Places     w      x   y    z  col
Date                                                   
1946-01-02  14:45:00     6.8  36.3  140.1  31  3.2    1
1946-01-02  22:18:00     7.6  40.5  141.4   0  4.6    3
1946-01-02  23:29:00     6.7  36.1  139.4  39  4.3    2
1946-01-03  04:28:00     5.6  34.4  136.5   1  4.2    2
1946-01-05  04:36:00     6.5  35.5  139.5  50  3.0    1

print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['1946-01-02', '1946-01-02', '1946-01-02', '1946-01-03',
               '1946-01-05'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

Create new DataFrame with [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start=df.index.min(), 
                                             end=df.index.max(), freq='D'))

print (dfx)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [1946-01-02 00:00:00, 1946-01-03 00:00:00, 1946-01-04 00:00:00, 1946-01-05 00:00:00]
```

And then use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = dfx.join(df)
print (df)
                Time  Places     w      x     y    z  col
1946-01-02  14:45:00     6.8  36.3  140.1  31.0  3.2  1.0
1946-01-02  22:18:00     7.6  40.5  141.4   0.0  4.6  3.0
1946-01-02  23:29:00     6.7  36.1  139.4  39.0  4.3  2.0
1946-01-03  04:28:00     5.6  34.4  136.5   1.0  4.2  2.0
1946-01-04       NaN     NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
1946-01-05  04:36:00     6.5  35.5  139.5  50.0  3.0  1.0
```

---

If there is `DatetimeIndex` with times create column by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (df)
                    Places     w      x   y    z  col
DateTime                                              
1946-01-02 14:45:00     6.8  36.3  140.1  31  3.2    1
1946-01-02 22:18:00     7.6  40.5  141.4   0  4.6    3
1946-01-02 23:29:00     6.7  36.1  139.4  39  4.3    2
1946-01-03 04:28:00     5.6  34.4  136.5   1  4.2    2
1946-01-05 04:36:00     6.5  35.5  139.5  50  3.0    1

print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['1946-01-02 14:45:00', '1946-01-02 22:18:00',
               '1946-01-02 23:29:00', '1946-01-03 04:28:00',
               '1946-01-05 04:36:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='DateTime', freq=None)
```

---

```
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
             DateTime  Places     w      x   y    z  col
0 1946-01-02 14:45:00     6.8  36.3  140.1  31  3.2    1
1 1946-01-02 22:18:00     7.6  40.5  141.4   0  4.6    3
2 1946-01-02 23:29:00     6.7  36.1  139.4  39  4.3    2
3 1946-01-03 04:28:00     5.6  34.4  136.5   1  4.2    2
4 1946-01-05 04:36:00     6.5  35.5  139.5  50  3.0    1
```

Then remove times by [`Series.str.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.normalize.html) and last [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with replace misisng values in `DateTime` column:

```
d = df['DateTime'].dt.normalize()
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'Dates':pd.date_range(start=d.min(), 
                                             end=d.max(), freq='D')})

print (dfx)
       Dates
0 1946-01-02
1 1946-01-03
2 1946-01-04
3 1946-01-05

df = dfx.merge(df.assign(Dates=d), on='Dates', how='left')
df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'].fillna(df['Dates'])
print (df)
       Dates            DateTime  Places     w      x     y    z  col
0 1946-01-02 1946-01-02 14:45:00     6.8  36.3  140.1  31.0  3.2  1.0
1 1946-01-02 1946-01-02 22:18:00     7.6  40.5  141.4   0.0  4.6  3.0
2 1946-01-02 1946-01-02 23:29:00     6.7  36.1  139.4  39.0  4.3  2.0
3 1946-01-03 1946-01-03 04:28:00     5.6  34.4  136.5   1.0  4.2  2.0
4 1946-01-04 1946-01-04 00:00:00     NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
5 1946-01-05 1946-01-05 04:36:00     6.5  35.5  139.5  50.0  3.0  1.0
```

Comment: I like this, didn't think to create an empty df with all the dates then merge them